# How to get location's name in android

Tags: java, android

Lets say I have the Long and Lat of a certain location.  Is it possible I can retrieve the name of the location? like jet's pizza or walmart...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is the full method of location. 
Just call this from any where. 
You will get the User's current location. with full street, city and country address

also you can pass latitude and longitude values to . `addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);` to get location of any particular values.

```
public String getUserLocation() {

    String address = "";

    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean network_enabled = locManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    Location location;

    if (network_enabled) {

        location = locManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();

            Log.e("longitude  = ", longitude + "lat");
            Log.e("latitude  = ", latitude + "long");

            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return address;
            }
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {

                String addressline = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

                Log.e("Address", addressline + ", " + city + ", " + country);
                return address = addressline + ", " + city + ", " + country;
            }

            return address;
        }
    }

    return address;

}
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: wah j jawab aa per samjh me na aayo :)

Comment: hal ray hal bishni.. :D

Answer (score 1):

[The Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) does that. It uses Internet, though, and is not as accurate as you'd like always, but it does the job.

Comment: I was reading a different post couple hours ago, they said that Geocoder doesn't work on all devices.  How true is that?

Comment: First time I hear about it not working on all devices. It's part of the SDK, not sure how it won't work. I've used it once and despite finding my "location" to be 50/100m from where I've been, I think in US perhaps it would do better (Europe here). 

I believe you can use [Google's direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), but that has some limits as far as I know. It works with requests (hence, limits). It returns JSON-parsed data consisting of coordinates (if you need to) and place name (street at least), but it is another source of location data.

Comment: P.S. Funny you accept the geocoder answer 5 minutes after I gave that... Hope it works for you at least.

Comment: I feel a shamed sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

In the Address object you have a lot of interesting stuff :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

like `getFeatureName()` for exemple.

To retrieve addresses from a lat/long coordinates :

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1); // the number of result you want, in your case probably just one.
```

Comment: Be aware of bugs that may require reboot to make Geocoder work again (after it suddently stop working). I'd use google web service for that